# Should CSS utility classes have the "!important" keyword?

Tags: css

Let’s say I have a few utility classes:

```
.primary-text {
    color: blue;
}
.danger-text {
    color: red;
}
.display-400 {
    width: 400px;
}
.max-width-100 {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Do classes like this require the `!important` keyword?

Comment: But if you are using bootstrap then these classes are already there, then it's not necessary.

Comment: The !important flag is a *big* hammer.  The biggest, in fact.  You should only use it if you are sure that you absolutely need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have some other CSS files that are loaded before this file, you have three ways to force your CSS content to load:

1. add *!important*
2. add your CSS file link tag at the end of another link tag
3. find a more accurate selector for your tag like this:

   ```
   span.primary-text {
       color: blue;
   }
   ```

This code has higher priority.

But if you don't use any other CSS file that contains these selectors with the same properties, you don’t need to use *!important*.